# developing a website for my institute

Tags: spring-mvc

i am working on spring.
actually i have created a home page for a website and i want return a contact page when i click on contact.I reached on controller and my page is returning from controller but not showing.so tell me how to hide current home page and show another returning page.

```
@Controller
public class ControllerClass 
{
    @RequestMapping(value="/kamil")

    public  String contactVal()
    {
        System.out.println("hii");
        return "/enquiry/contact";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println(); shows output on console and not webpage. Add data to Model and access it on the JSP page using EL.

In your controller:

```
model.addAttribute("hello","hello world");
```

On the JSP page:

```
${hello}
```

output:

```
hello world
```

Comment: when you click on the link to go to the contact page, what does it show ?